# UX principles while designing a logo ?

Tags: design

what would be the ux principles that needs to be considered while designing a logo ??

Although this [link](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3031328/the-makings-of-a-great-logo) gives a bit of an idea, it doesnt specifically mention any ux principle as such..

Comment: There aren't any, really. Other than maybe "don't make it ugly". Your logo is more about branding and marketing than UX.

Comment: Consider the nike logo, which is essentially a simple tick. Its neat, clean, not ugly.. but a person who doesnt know or is not aware of the brand nike, doesnt get any idea from the logo.. so is there a UX need there ??

Comment: @VInay Some would argue that the logo becomes recognizable after the company has established its brand. For example, the redesign of the Gap and Yahoo logos were not liked by many people (in fact Gap decided to change it back), but the brand name still stands.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Graphic Design rather than User Experience even if the question is stated as UX principles. A logotype doesn't have User Experience properties.

Answer (score 1):

No principles as such, and would suggest this is more of a graphic design question, however some factors to bare in mind would be to:

- Flat design is everywhere now, so making your logo flat would not be the worst move.
- A simple flat design also makes it easier to scale, say if you needed your logo to be displayed on a mobile device with a smaller screen size. Converting your file to svg would be helpful. Scalability is also important if you are going to print this on business cards etc.
- The text used in the logo to be as legible as possible, there is nothing worse than an unreadable logo.

Here is an article on logo best practices: http://www.medianovak.com/logo-design-best-practices/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You logo is essentially an icon for you company, so I can think of some usability considerations.

- Your logo should have a [distinct outline](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-distinct-icon-outlines-help-users-scan-faster/) so users can quickly recognise it when they are scanning to find you. This could be on a web page, or in their set of business cards / list of contacts.
- Any colours in the logo should also work for those who perceive colours differently (e.g. red/green colourblind).
- Avoid putting your company name in all caps. We [rely heavily on the shape of a word when we read](http://uxmovement.com/content/all-caps-hard-for-users-to-read/), and putting a word all in caps interferes with this process.
- If you leverage our existing knowledge of the world in you graphic, you can speed the association between your logo and either your company name or what you do. For example, a photography company might choose a logo shape that evokes the idea of a camera. A company with the word "swift" in their name might choose to use the outline of the bird with the same name.